# ANRs & crashes : Where has the register dump gone?

Tags: android, crash, reporting, native

In the Android Developer Console "ANRs & crashes" :

We have a few crashes in native code. I can work out the instruction causing the crash but it would be helpful if the register dump (that used to be present) was also saved with the crash report. Is there no way of getting hold of this? I'm pretty sure that was present a few months ago.

Comment: Are you talking about the tool in the developer console? Or in Android Studio? Or somewhere else? That's an important detail to add

Comment: Amended the question now, thanks.